# How to achieve this effect with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

hi guys, I have encountered some problems in using flutter. I want to achieve the following effect, but I'm confused. I don't know how to implement it?
I am a novice, I hope to get your help, thank you!
Here is the code that I implemented part of the effect

```dart
class _RollImg extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RollImgState createState() => _RollImgState();
}

class _RollImgState extends State<_RollImg>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List headerImage = [
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=31CMmjAGPUw03*cOYWkyYNTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=huHw8wzAtfMX8wA_MXrnoWTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=V6A0RzvlA1i0*G51vpDHXgTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=Iptw8l9fR4E8waiiLDV0*NTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=8A1dnfk3l4jiK4pekJfCfgTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=Qrzh71*ED0NOhRF2LIWWCWTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=JFjoiMrl5aQELmtBc_4s7gTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=SBGuL_2ypcDh5sU8IzqiwgTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=SAbIH2IXAx1neurGXeYNfWTT&type=taobao",
    "https://wwc.alicdn.com/avatar/getAvatar.do?userIdStrV2=31CMmjAGPUw03*cOYWkyYNTT&type=taobao"
  ];
 
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> prompterAnimation; 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1600),
      vsync: this, 
    )
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..repeat(reverse: true);
    prompterAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: S(60))
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInCubic))
        .chain(CurveTween(curve: Interval(0.3, 0.8)))
        .animate(controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `build` method of `_RollImgState `?

Comment: other code is here~
class _BeingRobbed extends StatelessWidget {
  const _BeingRobbed({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        _RollImg(),
        Text(
          "正在抢!>",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xfffe3738)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

Comment: So, you did not implement the `build` method of `_RollImgState` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm a novice. I don't know how to deal with this piece @Thierry